# "xxx has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement" on one device only

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

I'm testing an iCloud-enabled App that uses the iCloud key-value store.

I'm testing it on an iPad and an iPod, both running 5.1.1.

Today, with no apparent reason, running on the iPad (and on the iPad only) causes the message "xxx  has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement" to be shown and I cannot access the key-value store, which means that I cannot run the App on that device.

Accessing the iCloud file sore works fine.

The provisioning profie hasn't changed, the entitlement file hasn't changed, the project and target settings haven't changed, and the code still runs fine on the iPod.

There's only one target for all devices.

Removing the App from the iPad and re-installing it doesn't help. Product Clean doesn't help. Removing the iPad from the Xcode organizer and re-enabling it doesn't help. Removing all the App's data from iCloud doesn't help. As far as I can tell, nothing helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: I Recently ran into the same exact problem, on my iPhone 4S w/ 5.0.1. I was under the impression that it would work If I restored my device, which people have recommended doing and seems to work for some.

Restoring did not work for me, What I did was try it another device, my iPad and it worked without changing anything. So I didn't run into the problem in the Simulator or my iPad, but problem occurs only on my iPhone 4S. I'll upvote this question, because I need an answer as well.

Comment: I had the same problem: I had to edit my provisioning profile to add in the device ID (again), re-import the profile, delete the app & rebuild... then success.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen problems with older profiles being cached / sticking around on the device.

You might try opening Settings:

- Go to General -> Profiles.
- Delete all the profiles related to this app.
- Delete the app.
- Re-install the app and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm using unity3d, but have the same problem. Enabled iCloud in dev. rebuilt provisioning. clean build to new project folder. xcode generated entitlements (which appear to match app id/bundle correctly) deleted all old profiles from device, and old certificates from mac. run app, still get same errors...  any other ideas ?  Help appreciated.

Comment: ..I should add... Xcode 5, and I have a projectName.entitlements  file, but maybe not an entitlements.plist file that some have mentioned, where is this and what should be in it please ?

Answer (score 0):

Noticed yesterday that the automatically generated entitlement file does not contain all the required entitlements. One is for document storage, the other for key-value pair data.

"ubiquity-container-identifiers"   and   "iCloud Key-Value Store"

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingiCloud.html)
...also, make sure the entitlements file is listed in " Code Signing->Code Signing Entitlements" tab in build settings, for both release and debug.

Comment: Are doe it need it in target or project ?